# VB SQL Error 3061: Too few Parameters

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have the following code:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Employees SET Login =" & Me.LoginTxt & ",FirstName ='" & Me.FNameTxt & "'" & ",LastName ='" & Me.LNameTxt & "'" & _
    ",HourlyRate ='" & Me.HRateTxt & "'" & ",ShopID ='" & Me.ShopIDCmbo & "'" & ",HomePhone ='" & Me.HomePhoneTxt & "'" & _
    " WHERE ID =" & Me.IDtxt.Value
```

I get a *Runtime Error 3061: Too few parameters. Expected 1.*

It tells me the error is in the last part, ie. `" WHERE ID =" & Me.IDtxt.Value` 
I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix this

Comment: Keep in mind that you are _extremely_ vulnerable to a sql injection attack with this code.  You should use parameterized queries to avoid this.  Imagine what would happen if the user typed `April Fools!'; Drop Table Employees; --` in your Me.LoginTxt textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please construct the SQL Statement in a string, make the program output it, and add it in your post.

This will help us understanding what's wrong.

If I have to guess, I would add quotes around Me.LoginTxt parameter.

Comment: I rewrote the statement and it turned out that as you said, the quotes were missing from  Me.LoginTxt